# Export as image with too many different (unused) colors

Tags: qgis

When I create a map, which uses 13 different colors (12 + gray for background), why uses(!!) QGIS more than 20000 different colors when saved as bmp, png or jpg?- I verified this behaviour with irfanview (image | information , used colors). As gif as an export-option is not available, how can I limit the number of used colors in the exported raster-files. reducing later in irfanview is not an option, because colors are also changed (e.g. replaced, dithered,...) not only eliminated.

I use QGIS 2.18.13 64bit under windows 10

[image]

Comment: can you export as png8?

Comment: What about turning off antialiasing?

Comment: @ndawson: thx, this is the solution, now I have only 13 used colors. If you post your comment as answer I can accept your answer

Comment: @nmtoken as far as i now there is no export option png8

Comment: It's looks like that you need indexed colours. The GIF format is most suitable for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely caused by the antialiasing used by default. If you turn it off from settings -> options -> rendering -> "Make lines appear less jagged at the expense of some rendering performance" then the output will ONLY have the selected colors, and not the "in between" shades used by antialiasing.