# Export as image with too many different (unused) colors in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

Using QGIS3 I am unable to export a map-image only with the colors in use. 
There was a solution for QGIS 2.x: [Export as image with too many different (unused) colors](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255792/export-as-image-with-too-many-different-unused-colors)
But settings -> options -> rendering -> "Make lines appear less jagged at the expense of some rendering performance" does no longer work!
In the Layout-Manager under Image Export Options I have also deselected anti-aliasing:

[image]

Is there any workaround?